# boost asio async_read_until: how to raise error from a custom MatchCondition?

Tags: c++, boost, network-programming, boost-asio

I am trying to optimize an application layer protocol that has a mixed mode protocol ( line protocol for meta info, handshake, acknowledgement, etc. and binary for data ). In a state where the client is waiting for an ACK, I do

```
async_read_until(socket, buffer, untill_crlf_maxbytes_1024_match_condition, handler);
```

Where `untill_crlf_maxbytes_1024_match_condition` is implemented acxcording to async_read_until documented [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read_until/overload4.html).

Here the idea is to read untill CR+LF but wait for only 1024 bytes to be read, so that if anything spooky goes on and if the socket gets some junk, it would not stay reading.

My question is, is it a good idea to raise an error in such a scenario from `untill_crlf_maxbytes_1024_match_condition`? How do I raise an error in that scenario? If not whats the best alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By *raise error*, do you mean *throw exception*? If so, it's a bad idea because most functions of boost asio have two versions: throwing exceptions and returning error codes. Error codes are very useful for asynchronous nature of boost asio.

You can return `true` from your `match condition` for all cases, including errors. Just check errors in you `handler`

Comment: Thanks AndyT, but that as I understand from the linked documentation, the bool return value only suggests whether the async_read can stop or not. It doesnt really tell the handler that there was an error; By error I mean the fact that a CR+LF was not found in 1024 bytes read so far.

Comment: @CodeMedic I think your handler could infer an error based on `bytes_transferred` placeholder being larger than 1024 bytes.

Comment: @CodeMedic, @Sam Miller: or any other convenient way, up to setting a global flag etc. boost::asio just doesn't provide you such facility

Comment: @CodeMedic: somebody downvoted this answer, I hope it's not you (no other critical comments here) because I tried to help and I believe I provided correct answer

Comment: @Andy FWIW I upvoted you since this seems like the best answer.

Comment: @AndyT, I think there is no easy way to do it other than checking `bytes_transferred`. So a combination of restricting read length from `untill_crlf_maxbytes_1024_match_condition` and `bytes_transferred` check from handler is the solution. Thanks Sam & Andy!